# Can someone help me understand the execution of this C program? (Beginner)

Tags: c, arrays, loops

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 main() 
 {
    int a[2][5], i,j; //2d array declaration

    for(i=0;i<=1;i++) //first loop for 1st dimension
    {
        for(j=0;j<=4;j++) //nested loop for 2nd dimention
        {
            printf("Value for a[%d][%d] is :  ", i,j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]); //asks for value
        }
    } 
 }
```

In this program, when the loop is executing, in the first run, i=0, and inside that j=0,1,2,3,4.
When this is done and it comes to the 2nd dimension where i=1, why does it run the nested loop again when the condition is already false (j<=4)?

Where are all these constant values saved? Does it restart the value of j when the nested loop is run again?

Comment: Aside: you are using magic numbers for the array dimensions and the loop iteration limits, yet they are worsened by introducing *different* magic numbers that refer to the same limit. So given that you hard-coded the array dimensions I would use the *same* values by rephrasing the loop `for(i=0; i<=1; i++)` as `for(i=0; i<2; i++)` ditto for the other one. Later, when you replace them with a variable or a defined name, you only have to look for one relevant value. It's also easier to follow the code.

Answer (score 3):

A `for` loop has three components (expressions) in the form `for (A;B;C)`:

- `A` - Pre-Iteration, run once at the start
- `B` - Loop Condition, tested *before* each iteration, including the first
- `C` - Post-Iteration, executed *after* each iteration

You're asking to initialize `j=0` each time the loop starts, then testing `j <= 4` which will be true. When the loop repeats it does `j++`, then tests again.

It's worth noting that these are all optional and `for (;;)` is valid, but is an infinite loop unless you `break` it.

Comment: So when the loop runs for the second time where i=1, j becomes 0?

Comment: As you requested by saying `for (j=0;..)`, yes. It's quite educational to step through this code in a debugger to see how it plays out.

Answer (score 2):

With minor improvements:

```
int main(void) //added int and void to main
 {
    int a[2][5], i,j; //2d array declaration

    for(i=0;i<2;i++) //first loop for 1st dimension
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++) //nested loop for 2nd dimention
        {
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]); //asks for value [note, before printf]
            printf("Value for a[%d][%d] is %d\n:  ", i,j, a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;//int main(void) requires a return statement
             //Note also, 'main()' is really not a proper signature for              
             //the main function 
 }
```

This code intends to assign values to each member of the 2D array by using prompted input values using `scanf`, but because of some syntax and logic errors, the original would not work as intended.  To help, the order of the two lines in the nested for loops has been switched to prevent the array from being accessed before being initialized.

The nested `for` loop indexes have been modified in this version to use the same values for limit, as those used to size the array in its declaration:

```
int a[2][5];
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    for(i=0;j<5;i++)
```

`scanf()` is the method used for user input.  Each call prompts for a value, which is placed into the corresponding row-column index indicated by `i` and `j`, and written to `stdout`.  Note the actual value in the original code is not printed out, but it is in this slightly modified version.

Answer (score 1):

The value of j is initialized to 0 each time you run the nested loop because you set the initialize expression of the for statement to "j=0"

That expression will be run for each execution of the outer loop